# Make one database column clone another column in the same table

Tags: mysql, database, authentication

in my social media site the registration page contain
Username and it must be unique username
name
last name
email
password

and in my tbl_user I have Id column which is  auto increment  and unique which is a primary key (init 11)
and the unique username from the registration  which is a key (varchar 32)

my users is having a trouble while registering there accounts
because they don't understand the deferent between the username and name

is there any way I can make the username column auto clone the id column and insert it as  varchar ?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more ways to do it and here is one of the ways:

1. Convert the ID from auto-increment to a number ex: `id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`
2. Create a sequence to serve as a generator instead of the auto-increment `CREATE SEQUENCE TheNameForMySeqnece`
3. Create a trigger before insert which will:

   - Get the next sequence number with `nextval(TheNameForMySeqnece)`
   - Populate the ID with the generated number
   - Populate the username with the ID (or some additional logic)